# Defining own Atlas server via environment variable

Tags: vagrant, environment-variables

Is it possible to define a company hosted atlas server via environment variable for vagrant commands.

I can use `vagrant box add ADDRESS` to download a box file from each server. If i use `vagrant box add hashicorp/precise64`vagrant downloads the box file from atlas.hashicorp.com.

What I'm looking for is a way to define an alternativ default Download location via environment variable, e.g. `VAGRANT_ATLAS=https://atlas.example.com`

Sure i can define such url in `Vagrantfile` or a above said in `vagrant box add`command. But this is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

`export VAGRANT_SERVER_URL=http://atlas.example.com`does the trick.

If I set this variable a `vagrant box add foo/bar` leads to this url

`http://atlas.example.com/foo/bar` and adds the box to your vagrant environment.